# What happens to --assume-unchanged files on sync?

Tags: git

I am working on a git code base. There are project xml files tracked by server that I would like to change. I want to set it up in a way that:

- My local change should be ignored and never sent to server.
- Server should overwrite my local change on sync.

Currently I use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [my file name]
```

But I am not sure what happens when server updates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged)

> `--[no-]assume-unchanged`
>
> ... When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, [this] allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git.
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; **thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.**

So, you will need to `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` the file before pulling in the changes.

#### Example

```
$ git status

  Changes not staged for commit:

      modified:   some-file.txt

$ git update-index --assume-unchanged some-file.txt

$ git status

  nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git pull

  a1b2c3d4..a4b3c2d1  master     -> origin/master
  Updating a1b2c3d4..a4b3c2d1
  error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
      some-file.txt
  Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
  Aborting
```

Comment: Incidentally, I found it obnoxious that there's no user-oriented command to *see* which index files have flags and/or clear such flags, so I wrote one: [`git-flagged`](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged).

Comment: I have the following in my **~/.gitconfig**: `[alias] assumed = "!git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-"`. So I can just run `git assumed` to see a list of the files. I'm guessing yours is a bit more feature-fledged than this though. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Yeah, you need to allow for `h`, `S`, and `s` to test for all three possible combinations of assume-unchanged and skip-worktree (after which you wouldn't want to just toss the status character).